# SourceProperty as Nested Directory in CopyFile

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to copy two file from existing location to new location using WIX Installer.
INSTALLDIR and Destination Directory are already defined. And In SourceProperty for first I want to use `INSTALLDIR\P\X\Y` and In second I want to use `INSTALLDIR\Q\X\Y`

```
<ComponentGroup Id="aYML" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
   <Component Id="CopyaYML" Guid="" Transitive="yes">
     <CopyFile Id ="aYMLcopy" SourceProperty="INSTALLDIR\P\X\Y" SourceName="A.yml" DestinationProperty="Destination"/>
     <CreateFolder/>
   </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
<ComponentGroup Id="bYML" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
   <Component Id="CopybYML" Guid="" Transitive="yes">
      <CopyFile Id ="bYMLcopy" SourceProperty="INSTALLDIR\Q\X\Y" SourceName="B.yml" DestinationProperty="Destination"/>
      <CreateFolder/>
   </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

As \ is not allowed in WIX how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [has to be](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html) a property name, which has a limited character set of letters, numbers, and underscores. You could use a `SetProperty` custom action (type 19) to format a value using the directory ID and the file name, or even the `[#fileId]` property format, though that's not reliable in older versions of Windows Installer.

Before `InstallFiles` but after `CostFinalize`, you could do something like this:

```xml
<SetProperty Id="AYMLPATH" Before="InstallFiles" Sequence="execute" value="[ParentDirectoryId]A.yml" />
```

Though, it may be easier to just use the `SourceDirectory` attribute and specify the directory ID.

Copying files, though, can cause issues for some servicing scenarios. For example, if you copy files in a patch, the changes can't be rolled back. If the files are small, just duplicate the files. There are even tricks to duplicating the file records, but keeping a single file blob in a CAB, but is outside the scope of this answer.